# Wordpress - If the first post

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm using this code to show my 10 homepage posts:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=homepage&showposts=10&order=DESC');?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I would like somehow to identify the first post and change the code only for the first post, 
For example first post should show me the_excerpt instead of the_title like this:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=homepage&showposts=10&order=DESC');?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable to count the number of posts you're looping through. If the counter is 0, you're on the first post:

```
<?
query_posts('category_name=homepage&showposts=10&order=DESC');
$i = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    $i == 0 ? the_excerpt() : the_title(); 
    the_content(); 
    $i++;
endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a counter that increments each loop.

Start it by 1

```
$count = 1;
```

each loop do `$count++;`

```
if ($count ==1){the_excerpt();} else{the_content();}
```